# How to prevent intersection observer from firing when passing over elements quickly

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, throttling, intersection-observer

In the code example below, there is a button to scroll to the bottom of the page, passing over six observed divs.

`isIntersecting` fires for each element as they pass through the viewport. Is it possible to throttle or add a delay to the trigger to prevent the intersection event for elements that are only briefly in the viewport?

Ideally, in the example below, the interaction counter would be `2` after clicking the scroll down button - one detection for the first element and one for the last element, ignoring those in between

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
const counter = document.querySelector('.counter');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  threshold: 0.5
});

let count = 0;

blocks.forEach(block => observer.observe(block));

function scrollDown(y = document.body.clientHeight) {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: y,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}

function callback(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      count++;
      counter.innerText = `Intersections: ${count}`;
      entry.target.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
    } else {
      entry.target.style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.block {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.counter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="counter"></p>
<button onclick="scrollDown();">Scroll To Bottom</button>

<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>

<button onclick="scrollDown(0);">Scroll To Top</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

- everytime an intersecting element is found,  increment `count` and perform the necessary handling in the `setTimeout` callback set to run after `500` milliseconds (this number can be changed in accordance to the scroll speed)
- store the number returned by `setTimeout` in a variable
- when setting the `setTimeout`, check whether the variable contains a value. If so, use `clearTimeout` to remove that `setTimeout`, so whatever code you scheduled to execute won't run.
- once you've stopped scrolling, the code in the callback of the `setTimeout` will execute, and only the last element scrolled to will be handled (since previous `setTimeout`s to handle the other elements were cleared).

---

```js
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
const counter = document.querySelector('.counter');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);

let count = 0;

blocks.forEach(block => observer.observe(block));

function scrollDown(y = document.body.clientHeight) {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: y,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}

var lastTimeout;

function callback(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      if (lastTimeout) clearTimeout(lastTimeout)
      lastTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        count++;
        counter.innerText = `Intersections: ${count}`;
        entry.target.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
      }, 500);
    } else {
      entry.target.style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.block {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.counter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="counter"></p>
<button onclick="scrollDown();">Scroll To Bottom</button>

<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>

<button onclick="scrollDown(0);">Scroll To Top</button>
```

Comment: Nice.  Possible improvement: Detect when two elements are still intersecting when scrolling stops.